# How do I display solution in GEKKO GUI?

Tags: python, user-interface, gekko

I would like to explore the functionality of the GEKKO web GUI for visualising results as described in  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/326740143_GEKKO_optimization_suite.

I have enabled `m.options.WEB=1` and solved with `m.solve(GUI=True)`.

The GUI spawns but with no trends as expected (see below).  How do I show the variable content and how are the web interface html files generated used by the GUI?
[image: Global Options]
[image: Variable display]
[image: HTML files]

Comment: The GUI interface is nice, but my preference is to send the data with interface tags to the DCS and use the built-in historian and plotting features. However, it is challenging to see future move plans so this GUI fills that role. Configuration such as `STATUS` (On/Off), `REQCTRLMODE` (Requested Control Mode: Cold, Warm, On), constraints (`Upper`, `Lower` bounds on MVs) should all be made in the DCS and read into the application. This GUI interface allows those to be set, but it should really be done at the control system level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Gekko` display version is with `GUI=True` as is shown by the plot in your question. Only `FV`, `MV`, `SV`, and `CV` values display in the web interface.

**Edit:** As noted in your comment, you resolved the lack of trend display by upgrading `flask`.

```bash
pip install flask --upgrade
```

[image: Gekko web interface]

The option `WEB` is the APMonitor version of the web-interface that uses AJAX and Flash plots (deprecated, to be replaced in a future version) to display the web interface. This can remain as `m.options.WEB=0` to use the Gekko GUI.

Below is an example that generates the web-interface. The `flask` package is a dependency for the web-interface and the web-page needs to be refreshed the first time it is launched. Select the variables on the plot to display or add a new plot.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

m = GEKKO()
m.time = np.linspace(0,20,41)

# Parameters
mass = 500
b = m.Param(value=50)
K = m.Param(value=0.8)

# Manipulated variable
p = m.MV(value=0, lb=0, ub=100)
p.STATUS = 1  # allow optimizer to change
p.DCOST = 0.1 # smooth out gas pedal movement
p.DMAX = 20   # slow down change of gas pedal

# Controlled Variable
v = m.CV(value=0)
v.STATUS = 1  # add the SP to the objective
m.options.CV_TYPE = 2 # squared error
v.SP = 40     # set point
v.TR_INIT = 1 # set point trajectory
v.TAU = 5     # time constant of trajectory

# Process model
m.Equation(mass*v.dt() == -v*b + K*b*p)

m.options.IMODE = 6 # control
m.solve(disp=False,GUI=True)
```

Calling `m.solve(GUI=True)` generates (or updates) the web-interface with each call. It is also possible to display the MPC solution with Matplotlib.

[image: Matplotlib plot]

```py
# get additional solution information
import json
with open(m.path+'//results.json') as f:
    results = json.load(f)

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time,p.value,'b-',label='MV Optimized')
plt.legend()
plt.ylabel('Input')
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(m.time,results['v1.tr'],'k-',label='Reference Trajectory')
plt.plot(m.time,v.value,'r--',label='CV Response')
plt.ylabel('Output')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

More [complicated Matplotlib plots](https://apmonitor.com/do/uploads/Main/tclab_mhe_mpc.mp4) can also be generated to show a future prediction horizon, moving horizon estimation, or other customized features of the MPC solution.

Comment: The Flask dependency is installed,  and page is refreshed but I do not see the trends, even running with sample code.     Default browser is Chrome.  Is there anything else I can check?

Comment: I managed to sort the issue out with upgrading ```flask``` to 2.1.2

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar issue with the variables not being in the GUI. Flask is up to date, version 2.2.2...

I've found to ways that make them disappear would like to understand ways to work around this that don't require all the objects to be in the global scope.

Running the example above works the GUI shows the variables and their results.  But when init is separated into a function call (see 1st code block below) and the call to solve outside of it in python the GUI doesn't work. I've also observed if I place the variables under the model using the dot notation (2nd code block) so I can pass the model and all of it's variables around example m.u = m.MV() instead of u=m.MV() the GUI also stops showing the variables.

Passing model from function

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def init():
    m = GEKKO()
    m.time = np.linspace(0,20,41)

    # Parameters
    mass = 500
    b = m.Param(value=50)
    K = m.Param(value=0.8)

    # Manipulated variable
    p = m.MV(value=0, lb=0, ub=100)
    p.STATUS = 1  # allow optimizer to change
    p.DCOST = 0.1 # smooth out gas pedal movement
    p.DMAX = 20   # slow down change of gas pedal

    # Controlled Variable
    v = m.CV(value=0)
    v.STATUS = 1  # add the SP to the objective
    m.options.CV_TYPE = 2 # squared error
    v.SP = 40     # set point
    v.TR_INIT = 1 # set point trajectory
    v.TAU = 5     # time constant of trajectory

    # Process model
    m.Equation(mass*v.dt() == -v*b + K*b*p)

    m.options.IMODE = 6 # control
    return m

m=init()
m.solve(disp=False,GUI=True)
```

Using dot notation to group variables with model

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = GEKKO()
m.time = np.linspace(0,20,41)

# Parameters
mass = 500
b = m.Param(value=50)
K = m.Param(value=0.8)

# Manipulated variable
m.p = m.MV(value=0, lb=0, ub=100)
m.p.STATUS = 1  # allow optimizer to change
m.p.DCOST = 0.1 # smooth out gas pedal movement
m.p.DMAX = 20   # slow down change of gas pedal

# Controlled Variable
m.v = m.CV(value=0)
m.v.STATUS = 1  # add the SP to the objective
m.options.CV_TYPE = 2 # squared error
m.v.SP = 40     # set point
m.v.TR_INIT = 1 # set point trajectory
m.v.TAU = 5     # time constant of trajectory

# Process model
m.Equation(mass*m.v.dt() == -m.v*b + K*b*m.p)

m.options.IMODE = 6 # control
m.solve(disp=False,GUI=True)
```

Param show but variables are missing!
[image: Param show but variables are missing!]

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33514188)